# Get response from Laravel API in React Native

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs, react-native

I created an mobile application with React Native and i want use Laravel as backend. I created a register page to allow user register account through mobile application.

When user press register button on mobile application. It will send request to laravel and return response.In my Register.js

```
async onRegisterPressed() {
    try{
        let response= await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user:{
                    name:this.state.name,
                    email:this.state.email,
                    password:this.state.password,
                    password_confirmation:this.state.password_confirmation,
                }
            })
        });

        let res= await response.text();
        console.log("res is" + res);
    }catch(errors){

    }
}
```

But in my Laravel Controller. I am not sure how to return the response of form validation.

My Api\RegisterController

```
    public function register(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
            'gender'=>'required|bool'
        ]);
}
```

So how to get all errors and return it to react native? And should it be json format or Text format? Hope you guys can give me some hints because i just learn react native.

Comment: Is that a question directed to React or Laravel? It's confusing. `validate()` comes from the `ValidatesRequests` trait. You can take a look at that class and either override `formatValidationErrors()` to fit your needs or do something else.

Comment: Hi @IvankaTodorova , you can assume this as using react native as Frontend and using Laravel as Backend.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Laravel it should simply be:

```
return redirect('view')->withErrors($validator);
```

you can read more about this here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation